# Sum the results of looking up multiple reference values

Tags: excel, vlookup, sumifs, array-formulas

I am seeking a formula to replace my current method of adding another vlookup to my formula string each time another week passes (the current formulas in the cells in column D).  i.e - I would like it to look through my header row (Row 2) for the referenced weeks and find each one of them in my lookup table (FTE_Lookup) to sum all of the corresponding possible hours for those weeks.  I read a couple threads on Sumproduct for multiple vlookups, but it doesn't quite match my situation.  Below is a a link to my dummied-down spreadsheet for an example.  The data in Row 2; Column D; and the FTE_Lookup table are of interest to this problem:

https://drive.google.com/a/vt.edu/file/d/0B7LOhGW3xbKgbGUxS2x1anNfV00/view?usp=sharing

[image: Vlookup Image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: post the data as text and the formula you tried as text please.  your link requires confirmation.

Comment: too much data to post as text.  Can I post picture?

Comment: =E4/(VLOOKUP(G$2,FTE_Lookup,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(M$2,FTE_Lookup,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($J$2,FTE_Lookup,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($P$2,FTE_Lookup,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($S$2,FTE_Lookup,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($V$2,FTE_Lookup,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($Y$2,FTE_Lookup,2,FALSE))

Comment: Image added....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to split the lookup named range to its two columns. I used `FTE_Lookup_1` for the date column and `FTE_Lookup_2` for the return value column

Then use this array formula:

```
=E4/SUM(IF((MOD(COLUMN($E$2:$FG$2)-5,3)=2)*($E$2:$FG$2<>""),LOOKUP($E$2:$FG$2,FTE_Lookup_1,FTE_Lookup_2)))
```

being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is a great solution.  Could you explain the -5,3)=2) part for me, just for my own understanding?  My only problem now is that the array formulas really bog down my file each time I refresh with new data.  My "Distinct Headcount" is also being calculated with array formulas, which takes my computer at least 30 minutes to finish each.  I don't think this one will be as taxing, though.  Thanks!